# How to calculate point y with given point x of a angled line

Tags: geometry

I dropped out of school to early I guess, but I bet you guys can help me here.
I've got a sloped line starting from point a(0|130) and ending at b(700|0).

I need an equation to calculate the y-coordinate when the point x is given, e.g. 300. Can someone help me please ? 
Sorry for asking such a dumb question, can't find any answer here, propably just too silly to get the math slang ;)

Comment: Math can be so simple when you're stupid :D

Comment: Thanks for your answers, helped me a lot, now I can draw some text in my php script at the right point :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have a point $(0, 130)$ and another point $(700, 0)$. The equation for this line would then be $y = -\dfrac{130}{700} (x) + 130$. So to get the height at a particular x, you just plug x into this equation.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation) is another reference.

Answer (score 1):

You want the [two point form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation) of a linear equation.  If your points are $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, the equation is $y-y_1=(x-x_1)\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$.  In your case, $y=-\frac{130}{700}(x-700)$